# What exactly is a Set in Coq

Tags: coq, type-theory

I'm still puzzled what the sort **Set** means in Coq. When do I use **Set** and when do I use **Type**?

In Hott a **Set** is defined as a type, where identity proofs are unique.
But I think in Coq it has a different interpretation.

Comment: It's sorta-kinda (heh) `Type 0`, where `Type 0 : Type 1 : Type 2 : …`.

Comment: I am confused what Adam Chlipala means by `Second, there is the : Set fragment, which declares that we are defining a datatype that should be thought of as a constituent of programs. Later,` which I don't understand what it means. Why didn't he just use `Type`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Set` means rather different things in Coq and HoTT.

In Coq, every object has a type, including types themselves. Types of types are usually referred to as *sorts*, *kinds* or *universes*. In Coq, the (computationally relevant) universes are `Set`, and `Type_i`, where `i` ranges over natural numbers (0, 1, 2, 3, ...). We have the following inclusions:

```
Set <= Type_0 <= Type_1 <= Type_2 <= ...
```

These universes are typed as follows:

```
 Set : Type_i     for any i

Type_i : Type_j  for any i < j
```

Like in Hott, this stratification is needed to ensure logical consistency. As Antal pointed out, `Set` behaves mostly like the smallest `Type`, with one exception: it can be made *impredicative* when you invoke `coqtop` with the `-impredicative-set` option. Concretely, this means that `forall X : Set, A` is of type `Set` whenever `A` is. In contrast, `forall X : Type_i, A` is of type `Type_(i + 1)`, even when `A` has type `Type_i`.

The reason for this difference is that, due to logical paradoxes, only the lowest level of such a hierarchy can be made impredicative. You may then wonder then why `Set` is not made impredicative by default. This is because an impredicative `Set` is inconsistent with a strong form of the axiom of the excluded middle:

```
forall P : Prop, {P} + {~ P}.
```

What this axiom allows you to do is to write functions that can decide arbitrary propositions. Note that the `{P} + {~ P}` type lives in `Set`, and not `Prop`. The usual form of the excluded middle, `forall P : Prop, P \/ ~ P`, cannot be used in the same way, because things that live in `Prop` cannot be used in a computationally relevant way.

Comment: Does that imply that I do not need the Set sort if I do not need impredicativity?

Comment: I would say so, unless there's some weird corner case of the theory I'm not aware of. I always use Type instead.

Comment: What is impredicativity?

Comment: @CharlieParker In this context, it means that `forall T : Set, S T` has type `Set` (instead of `Type`) whenever `S T : Set`.

Comment: So, by using the option *-impredicative-set*, one can prove that `(forall P : Prop, {P} + {~ P}) -> False`, right? How does it work?

Comment: @Bob This deserves to be posted as a separate question! ;)

Comment: I'm confused, what is an concrete example that shows when one would want `Set` and not `Type`?

Comment: To add more context, apologies for two questions in a row hopefully I doesn't make one to be forgotten...but I am confused what Adam Chlipala means by `Second, there is the : Set fragment, which declares that we are defining a datatype that should be thought of as a constituent of programs. Later,` which I don't understand what it means. Why didn't he just use `Type`?

Comment: @CharlieParker You should ask this as a separate question so that others can help reply to it!

Comment: Sounds good! Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68056978/what-is-a-concrete-example-of-the-type-set-and-what-is-the-meaning-of-set hopefully the question is not too convoluted.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Arthur's answer:

From the fact that `Set` is located at the bottom of the hierarchy,

> it follows that `Set` is the type of the “small” datatypes and function types, i.e. the ones whose values do not directly or indirectly involve types.

That means the following will fail:

```
Fail Inductive Ts  : Set :=
  | constrS : Set -> Ts.
```

with this error message:

> Large non-propositional inductive types must be in `Type`.

As the message suggests, we can amend it by using `Type`:

```
Inductive Tt : Type :=
  | constrT : Set -> Tt.
```

Reference:

- The Essence of Coq as a Formal System by B. Jacobs (2013), [pdf](http://www.cs.kuleuven.be/~bartj/coq-essence.pdf).

Comment: I am confused what Adam Chlipala means by `Second, there is the : Set fragment, which declares that we are defining a datatype that should be thought of as a constituent of programs`. Later, which I don't understand what it means. Why didn't he just use `Type`? (btw really nice link you sent!)

Comment: @CharlieParker I guess Adam wanted to be really precise. `Type` would have worked too. But one needs to keep in mind that `Type` really means `Type@{level}` and the typechecker needs to figure out the universe level. but in this case, one would be delegating this decision to the typechecker. Instead, you can fix it apriori. FWIW, Conor McBride puts it like this: Coq stratifies types by ‘size’ into sets-of-values, sets-of-sets-of-values, and so on.