# What is a concrete example of the type `Set` and what is the meaning of `Set`?

Tags: coq

I've been trying to understand what `Set` is after encountering it in Adam Chlipala's book in addition to [this great discussion in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601502/what-exactly-is-a-set-in-coq). His first example definition binary ops using `Set`:

```
Inductive binop : Set := Plus | Times.
```

in that book he says:

```
Second, there is the : Set fragment, which declares that we are defining a datatype that should be thought of as a constituent of programs.
```

Which confuses me. What does Adam mean here?

In addition, I thought that some additional concrete examples would help my understanding. I am not an expert of Coq so I am not sure what type of examples would help but something simple and very concrete/grounded might be useful.

Note, I have seen that `Set` is the first "type set" in a the type hierarchy e.g. `Set = Type(0) <= Type = Type(1) <= Type(2) <= ...` . I guess this sort of makes sense intuitively like I'd assume `nat \in Type` and all usual programming types to be in it but not sure what would be in `Type` that wouldn't be in `Set`. Perhaps recursive types? Not sure if that is the right example but I am trying to wrap my head around what this concept means and it's conceptual (& practical) usefulness.

Answer (score 4):

Though `Set` and `Type` are different in Coq, this is mostly due to historical reasons. Nowadays, most developments do not rely on `Set` being different from `Type`. In particular, Adam's comment would also make sense if you replace `Set` by `Type` everywhere. The main point is that, when you want to define a datatype that you can compute with during execution (e.g. a number), you want to put it in `Set` or `Type` *rather than* `Prop`. This is because things that live in `Prop` are erased when you extract programs from Coq, so something defined in `Prop` would end up not computing anything.

As for your second question: `Set` is something that lives in `Type`, but not in `Set`, as the following snippet shows.

```
Check Set : Type. (* This works *)
Fail Check Set : Set.
(* The command has indeed failed with message: *)
(* The term "Set" has type "Type" while it is expected to have type  *)
(* "Set" (universe inconsistency: Cannot enforce Set+1 <= Set). *)
```

This restriction is in place to prevent paradoxes in the theory.  This is pretty much the only difference you see between `Set` and `Type` by default. You can also make them more different by invoking Coq with the `-impredicative-set` option:

```
(* Needs -impredicative-set; otherwise, the first line will also fail.*)
Check (forall A : Set, A -> A) : Set.
Universe u.
Fail Check (forall A : Type@{u}, A -> A) : Type@{u}.
(* The command has indeed failed with message: *)
(* The term "forall A : Type, A -> A" has type "Type@{u+1}" *)
(* while it is expected to have type "Type@{u}" (universe inconsistency: Cannot enforce *)
(* u < u because u = u). *)
```

Note that I had to add the `Universe u.` declaration to force the two occurrences of `Type` to be at the same level. Without this declaration, Coq would silently put the two `Type`s at different universe levels, and the command would be accepted. (This would not mean that `Type` would have the same behavior as `Set` in this example, since `Type@{u}` and `Type@{v}` are different things when `u` and `v` are different!)

If you're wondering why this feature is useful, it is not by chance. The overwhelming majority of Coq developments does not rely on it. It is turned off by default because it is incompatible with a few axioms that are generally considered more useful in Coq developments, such as the strong law of the excluded middle:

```
forall A : Prop, {A} + {~ A}
```

With `-impredicative-set` turned on, this axiom yields a paradox, while it is safe to use by default.

Comment: Arthur's answer is just great. Only thing I would like to add you may want see the link below since it is related very closely  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55868122/2747511

Comment: hi Arthur! Thanks for the great response! I was wondering, can you expand of what `Second, there is the : Set fragment, which declares that we are defining a datatype that should be thought of as a constituent of programs.
` really means and how it relates to different types of sorts? Even if it still applies to Type I hate to admit I still find that comment sort of confusing. Like every datatype I think of is just a new type not a new program (although it can) so I was sort of confused on what that comment was really to communicate to the reader. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @CharlieParker Note that Adam said "a constituent of programs", and not just "a program". In other words, a datatype declaration is part of a program in a traditional programming language, but not the _entire_ program. By contrast, a proposition is, in a sense, not part of the program, since it does not affect how it executes.