# In Coq, why is `nat` a `Type`, even though it's actually a `Set`?

Tags: types, coq

`Check nat. (* => Set *)`

But I'm able to pass `nat` to functions that take a parameter of type `Type`, even though `Set` and `Type` aren't the same. That being said, `Type` clearly isn't just a catch-all -- for example, trying to pass the literal `5` (a value of type `nat`) to a function that takes a parameter of type `Type` causes an error.

So why are objects of type `Set` allowed where it expects `Type`, but values of type `nat` are not allowed?

Answer (score 1):

A type is a collection of objects, which all behave *similarly*.  This is used pragmatically to ensure that functions are used correctly.  For instance, if you say that a function takes as input a natural number, you expect it to work correctly if it receives `1` as input and also if it receives `3` as input.  In this respect, `1` and `3` behave similarly.

Now, `nat` is the name of the collection.  It is very different from the number `1` or `3`, don't you agree?  This is why you can't pass `1` or `3` as arguments to a function that would accept `nat` as argument.

But what is the type of `nat`?  Well, `nat` is a type, so one would expect to write `nat : Type`, to say exactly that, but there is a subtlety.  It comes from the fact that `Type` itself should have a type.

In Coq, there is an almost invisible sequence of objects named `Type_0` `Type_1`, such that `Type_0 : Type_1`, `Type_1 : Type_2`, etc, with a subtyping rule so `x : Type_i` is enough to also have `x : Type_(i+1)`, and technically, `Set` is just another name for `Type_0`.  In other words, `Set` is the type for all types whose elements are not themselves types.

Every object of type `Set` also has type `Type_i`.

By default, the index `i` of `Type_i` is not printed, so sometimes it is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, `Set` is a subtype of `Type`, so every `T` that is a `Set` can be used where a `Type` is expected.

You might also be interested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39606239/1633770), which discusses the differences between `Set` and `Type`.

Comment: You can also read the section about typing rules in the [manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/cic.html).